# Cannot update an activity in an inbox feed

Tags: getstream-io

is it even possible to update an activity in an inbox feed?

```js
    const activityRequest = {
      actor: `ContentFeed:${origin}`,
      verb: "follow",
      object: `User:${destination}`,
      foreign_id: "...:followRequest:5fb68...",
      time: new Date().toISOString(),
    };

    const res = await getStreamAdminClient
      .updateActivity(activityRequest)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I'm trying to update the verb of the activity from followRequest to follow.
I'm getting a 200OK from getstream but it doesn't update the activity at all. The foreign id is definitely correct. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Foreign id / time pair should be exactly same. Otherwise, you're inserting a new activity.